# net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE on using Skype web sdk to login

Tags: javascript, skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I'm using skype web sdk to create an application.

Here is the code to sign in:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".sfb_widget", function() {
        client.signInManager.signIn({
            username: "myname@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
            password: "mypassword"
        }).then(function() {
            log('Logged In Succesfully');
            //$('#searchagain').show();
        }).then(null, function(error) {
            // if either of the operations above fails, tell the user about the problem
            //console.error(error);
            log('Oops, Something went wrong: ' + error);
        });
    })
```

On click of the button i'm getting the following error:

> GET https://lyncdiscover.mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/xframe
>   net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
>
> https://lyncdiscoverinternal.mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/xframe
>   net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: I would suggest browsing to https://lyncdiscoverinternal.mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/xframe and checking if the certificate is expired or needs to be accepted.  Typically Chrome reports this error when trying to load resources from HTTP when on HTTPS or when a certificate is invalid or expired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Skype for Bussiness online, you should use Authentication using **Azure AD**. 
Please read this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/developingucwaapplicationsforsfbonline

In your example, you are trying to use password authentication, that works for on-premise Skype for Bussiness only.

Comment: I'm trying to use the sample application available on the Skype Web SDK documentation but I can't log-in with my skype for business credentials. I've got the same error. Do you know how to make the login works over the skype on premisse sample application? Thank you.

Comment: First of all, on Skype for Bussiness servers you should add your domain to cross domain authorization list. Please read https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/ITAdmin-Configuration (skype web sdk using UCWA Rest Services)